# Installation of libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit failed : unmet dependencies

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management

Trying to install CDH4 (Cloudera Hadoop) and Manager on 12.04 LTS with 3.2.0-56-generic kernel and the installation aborts on the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit : Depends: libsasl2-modules (= 2.1.25.dfsg1-3) but 2.1.25.dfsg1-3ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Doing an apt-get install on libsasl2-modules comes back with

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-modules
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libsasl2-modules is already the newest version.
```

So `libsasl2-modules` is installed at the most up-to-date version.
What's missing?
I don't seem to be able to find `2.1.25.dfsg1-3ubuntu0.1` anywhere.

Greatly appreciated,

This is the `apt-get check` output...

```
sudo apt-get check  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done
```

Thanks again,

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get check`?

Comment: What is the result of `apt-cache madison libsasl2-modules`?

Answer (score 0):

```
libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit <- depend on libsasl2-modules
```

case 1 : `libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit` instead of `libsasl2`
case 1 result is `libc6 <- depend on ubuntu-desktop`

I guess.. The CDH release target is ubuntu server. (none gui).